# image does not update flutter

Tags: image, flutter

i'm using this function to get image from network, the problem is that even if I change the url it keeps the same image so it doesn't want to update

```js
 Future<ui.Image> getImage(String path) async {
    var img = new NetworkImage(path);
    img.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info,bool _){
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
    completer.complete(info);
    }    
    }));
    ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
    return imageInfo.image;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has it's own way of fetching network images like this:

```
Image.network('https://example.com/image.jpg');
```

In case image is a vector, you can use plugin for fetching svg called [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) that has similar syntax:

```
SvgPicture.network('https://example.com/image.jpg');
```

Both options will update UI automatically once picture is fetched from web. If none of those work for your case, you can also use manual call of `setState` to trigger UI refresh with fetched data.